# Multiple Aggregations on columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to display the percent as a result from grouping by 'type' as well as calculate the sum of two specific columns individually.

**Data**

```
free    use type    date
10      5   A1      1/1/2021
20      1   A1      1/1/2021
40      2   B2      1/1/2021
60      3   B2      1/1/2021
```

**Desired**

```
type    percent    use   free  date

A1      50         6     30    1/1/2021
B2      50         5     100   1/1/2021
```

**Doing**

```
percent = count/total *100
df.groupby(['type, 'date']).sum()
```

This gives me all but the percent. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize` for percentage of original `DataFrame` and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for aggregate values:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['type', 'date'], as_index=False).sum()

df1['perc'] =  df1['type'].map(df['type'].value_counts(normalize=True)).mul(100)
print (df1)
  type      date  free  use  perc
0   A1  1/1/2021    30    6  50.0
1   B2  1/1/2021   100    5  50.0
```

Comment: Thank you- what does the normalize do?

Comment: @Lynn - It return percentages.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach -

#### Join the following pandas series object

`percent_series = pd.DataFrame(df.type.value_counts())['type']/len(df)*100`

**Output**

```
B     50.0
A1    50.0
Name: type, dtype: float64
```